# Svelte: How to manually stop subscribe?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a store that fetches data once in a while – according to user's actions. This is a store because its data is used globally and mainly all components needs the latest data available.

But, for one specific component, I only need the first data loaded.

For this component, there is no reason to keep a `subscribe()` function running after the first fetch. **So, how can I stop this subscribe function?**

The only example in [Svelte doc's](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions) uses `onDestroy()`, but I need to manually stop this `subscribe()`.

I tried with a simple "count" (if count > 1, unsubscribe), but it doesn't work.

```js
    import user from './store'
    
    let usersLoaded = 0
    
    const unsubscribe = user.subscribe(async (data) => {
        if(data.first_name !== null) {
            usersLoaded = usersLoaded + 1
        }
        
        if(usersLoaded > 1) {
            unsubscribe;
        }
    });
```

Here's a full working REPL:

→ https://svelte.dev/repl/95277204f8714b4b8d7f72b51da45e67?version=3.35.0

Answer (score 8):

You might try Svelte's [`get`](https://svelte.dev/docs#get). A subscription is meant for situations where you need to react to changes; it's a long-term relationship. If you just need the current value of the store, `get` is the way to go.

> Occasionally, you may need to retrieve the value of a store to which you're not subscribed. `get` allows you to do so.
>
> ```js
> import { get } from 'svelte/store';
>
> const value = get(store);
> ```

Answer (score 7):

I had to use `unsubscribe()` instead of `unsubscribe`

---

Here's the final working REPL with some improvements:
https://svelte.dev/repl/95277204f8714b4b8d7f72b51da45e67?version=3.35.0

Answer (score 4):

You can use auto subscribe: $user which will also auto unsubscribe.
Some more details in the docs.

Example:

```
let user1 = null;
$: if ($user?.first_name && !user1) {
    user1 = $user.first_name;
    console.log('first user', $user.first_name);
}
```

And you do not really need a writable store here. You can use a readable and use the set method to handle the fetch.

Something like:

```
const user = readable(defaultUser, set => {
   .... fetch the data ....
   .... set(data)
}
```

By the way: This is already async code and you can use set(data) to store the fetch result.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated: 04 Jan 2023**

Best way to unsubscribe is using `onDestroy` Svelte's hook

```
import { onDestroy } from "svelte"

const subcriber = page.subscribe((newPage) => handleChangePage(newPage.params.id))

onDestroy(subcriber)
```

Comment: Does onDestroy cancel the current subscription(s) immediately or only when the containing component is actually destroyed? For my use-case I just need a quick way to cancel all subscribers on a svelte writeable before I add a new one.

Comment: Yea, at the very least, you can't run onDestroy from inside a function triggered by the user (or anything outside of component initialization). Probs good for other use-cases but not mine where a subscribe on writeable is triggered by user action